# Chrome inline installation does not display popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to make an extension of the Chrome webstore be installed on my site through chrome.webstore.install function, however does not appear when I click the installation popup on the button below ..

**Source:**

```
<head>  
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlmdaeedalndkbecknjlofncilhlemph"> 
</head>     
<body>  
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>      
</body>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow inline installation to work through the app individually in the Chrome Store. Go to your developer dashboard here: [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)

Then go to the Chrome Extension and select "edit". Allow "inline installation" and click publish.

More information on this here: [Chrome Inline-Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation)